# Can I set up a non-linear (old style) animation with ViewPager2?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager, android-animation, android-viewpager2

I have recently replaced my `ViewPager` with a `ViewPager2`, however, the animation when swiping pages seems like it's robotic and non-linear, unlike the old one with a much smoother animation. Is there a way I can get the old one back?

Comment: ViewPager2 animates swiping with PagerSnapHelper, it is private field and you can not override it easily, only through reflection.

Answer (score 1):

Well,  the [Developer guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide#java) would definitely show you how to implement the `viewpager` in your code, but in order to get more smoother effect on you animation try implementing below code.

```
public class ParallaxPageTransformer implements ViewPager.PageTransformer {

        public void transformPage(View view, float position) {

            int pageWidth = view.getWidth();


             if (position < -1) { // [-Infinity,-1)
                    // This page is way off-screen to the left.
                    view.setAlpha(1);

                } else if (position <= 1) { // [-1,1]

                    dummyImageView.setTranslationX(-position * (pageWidth / 2)); //Half the normal speed

                } else { // (1,+Infinity]
                    // This page is way off-screen to the right.
                    view.setAlpha(1);
                }


        }
    }
```

This would provide you an animation like this :

[image]

You can also go through following links which will help you more on this :

http://andraskindler.com/blog/2013/create-viewpager-transitions-a-pagertransformer-example/

http://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide.html#pagetransformer

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to customize animation in ViewPager2 appears to be through [PageTransformer](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/viewpager2/widget/ViewPager2.PageTransformer.html).  There aren't included drop-in replacements, but you can create your own transitions:

```
class MyPageTransformer : ViewPager2.PageTransformer {
  override fun transformPage(view: View, position: Float) {
    // position is the offset from center, negative being left
    // make changes to view based on pages position
    // e.g. view.alpha = min(0f, 1f - abs(position))
  }
}

...

viewPager.setPageTransformer(MyPageTransformer())
```

See examples in the [Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide-2#pagetransformer) for ViewPager2 transitions.

Comment: I have seen this before and it didn't solve my issue

Comment: Sorry about that! Based on Bracadabra's response, there may not be options besides using reflection to override the animation behavior or switching away from ViewPager2.

What particular issues did you run into using the Transformer?  Are you not able to access the properties you want to animate?  Or are you able to specify them but the animation doesn't render correctly?